# How do we connect and bind openldap user using php wamp server

Tags: php, windows, ldap, wamp, openldap

I've installed openldap setup for windows and using these details of ldap user

ip address : http://localhost/
full distinguished name :cn=name,cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com,
server name: ldap://server1
pasword : secret
domain : mydomain.com

now i am trying to get username=name given in the code below to be authenticated from ldap server . It is connecting but data bind and search are generating these errors.


Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\wamp\www\ldap authentication\connect.php on line 14





Warning: ldap_search(): supplied argument is not a valid ldap link resource in C:\wamp\www\ldap authentication\connect.php on line 15

I am new at ldap never used before . could anyone tell me where am i wrong or missing something. I am using this code given below.

```
<?php
$domain = 'mydomain.com';
$username = 'name';
$password = 'secret';
$ldapconfig['host'] = 'ldap://server1';
$ldapconfig['port'] = 389;
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=mydomain,dc=com';

$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$dn="cn=users,".$ldapconfig['basedn'];
$bind=ldap_bind($ds, $username .'@' .$domain, $password);
$isITuser = ldap_search($bind,$dn,'(&(objectClass=users)(sAMAccountName=' . $username. '))');
if ($isITuser) {
echo("Login correct");
} else {
echo("Login incorrect");
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. Check each `ldap_*` statement for errors before continuing!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to connect to an LDAP-Server using php.

```
ldap_connect('ldap.example.com', 389);
```

or

```
ldap_connect('ldap://ldap.example.org:389');
```

As far as I can see you are trying a mix of both which won't work.

Personally I like `ldap://ldap.example.org:389` as that's the only way to connect to ldaps-secured servers using `ldaps://ldap.example.org` (you do not need the port if it's the default port)